# How can I output from java code to the Jenkins console?

Tags: java, logging, ant, jenkins, console

I have java code with many `System.out.println()` added. One of them is at the start of the "main" method. When I start the code in NetBeans, I see the console output with all these `println`.

When I start the class in Jenkins/ant with fork&spawn set to true (as a separate task), it runs, but no println is put to the Jenkins console.

Can I make System.out.println to write to Jenkins console?

I have found an interesting [repaired Jenkins issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-18006), they say "a variable 'out' of the object model can be used to write messages to the build console" How?

Edit:
In the same project, the applications that are not spawned output their `stdout` into the Jenkins console OK.

Edit 2. 
Please, Notice that I want to output to Jenkins console, not to a file.

Answer (score 2):

If you overriding the method perform then, use BuildListener instance to get logger instance and write using print method.
Like this

```
@Override
public boolean perform(AbstractBuild build, Launcher launcher, BuildListener listener) {

    // This is where you 'build' the project.       /
    // This also shows how you can consult the global configuration of the builder
    listener.getLogger().println("Inside the Perform Method");
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[TaskListener](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/TaskListener.html#getLogger%28%29) of Jenkins has a method `getLogger()` using which you can print in the console output. `System.out.println` will not be redirected to Console output in Jenkins.

Comment: And how can I reach it from inside the code? "you can print" - how?

Comment: If you're extending [`perform`](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/tasks/BuildStep.html) in your plugin, you can reach to `getLogger` through [BuildListener](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/BuildListener.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect the output from a process to the Jenkins console, e.g. because you call some library code that writes to `System.out`, you can redirect the output of anything you call by using `System.setOut` / `System.setErr`.

```
@Override
public void perform(Run<?, ?> run, FilePath workspace, Launcher launcher, TaskListener listener)
     PrintStream outOriginal = System.out;
     PrintStream errOriginal = System.err;
     try {
        System.setOut(listener.getLogger());
        System.setErr(listener.getLogger());
        System.out.println("Testing System.out");
        // Call your code that writes to System.out by default
     } finally {
        System.setOut(outOriginal);
        System.setErr(errOriginal);
     }
}
```