# Jenkins - Console output doesn't work properly on Windows

Tags: windows, logging, jenkins, console, output

I have a simple hello world code in *main.c*. Jenkins runs that code with no problem but no printf is put to the Jenkins console.

Is there some configuration setting that has to be changed or some plugins that I have to install in order to print to Jenkins console?

Console output:

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace C:\Users\ozcanovunc\.jenkins\jobs\jenkins-test\workspace
 > git.exe rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git.exe config remote.origin.url https://github.com/ozcanovunc/jenkins-test.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/ozcanovunc/jenkins-test.git
 > git.exe --version # timeout=10
using .gitcredentials to set credentials
 > git.exe config --local credential.helper store --file=\"C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\git2428021638165579968.credentials\" # timeout=10
 > git.exe -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/ozcanovunc/jenkins-test.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git.exe config --local --remove-section credential # timeout=10
 > git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10
 > git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 615e0727146045f351ff36a80b41cd9c16b28aa2 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git.exe config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git.exe checkout -f 615e0727146045f351ff36a80b41cd9c16b28aa2
 > git.exe rev-list 615e0727146045f351ff36a80b41cd9c16b28aa2 # timeout=10
[workspace] $ C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe -xe C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\hudson1467373884410613106.sh
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\ozcanovunc\.jenkins\jobs\jenkins-test\workspace>Finished: SUCCESS
```

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
I know very similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24063233/how-can-i-output-from-java-code-to-the-jenkins-console) has been asked but no one seems to know anything about it. So I wanted to ask anyway.

**EDIT:**
Same configuration runs properly on Mac OS.

Answer (score 0):

```
[workspace] $ C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe -xe C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\hudson1467373884410613106.sh
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\ozcanovunc\.jenkins\jobs\jenkins-test\workspace>Finished: SUCCESS
```

This suggests that your Jenkins job is attempting to execute a Shell script block on Windows using `cmd.exe`, which won't execute the contents of the shell script.  You either have to install a Shell script runtime (i.e. Bash) on your Windows agent (and configure Jenkins to use `sh.exe` or leave it as the default to use `sh` in the PATH) or convert your job to use a Batch script block.

Answer (score -1):

Jenkins is a build tool. That means it compiles your code, builds all the necessary artifacts, run tests if provided, etc. It doesn't actually run your code (Only unit tests if they are provided).

So unless you are talking about a Jenkins Plugin that you wrote, you won't get to see your output to the console. But like you already mentioned, you are writing a simple hello world application.

Why would you want to print something from within your code to Jenkins anyway?

Comment: I don't actually want to print something. After running some tests, I want some log files to be generated and saved to my computer.

Comment: So you want a final build step that generates log files based on data created during the build? I'm not sure what it is exactly what you want, but you will probably need some kind of Jenkins plugin and fire it at the end of your build process. Looks like you have a different question than you original stated.

Comment: No, not exactly. All I want to do is to run an executable and redirect it's output to some file. In this case ./main >> log.txt. But in order to achieve that, I need to make sure that if I'm able to print something to Jenkins console.

Comment: I still don't understand why you just don't write the things you want to a log file from within your code. I don't get why you need to be able to print something to the output of Jenkins for that. Anyway, I only know how to write output to Jenkins console in Java: Use the getLogger of the TaskListener class. But I guess it won't really help you. Maybe you can find a substitute.

Comment: As I was saying, I was planning to redirect the output of my code to a log file which will be stored on my hard drive. I don't know if there is another way to achieve that. And how am I supposed to use the TaskListener class? Where am I gonna put that code?

Comment: I think we have some miscommunication. Output of your code is the printf statements you put in there. Output of your build is something different (this is what you see in the console of Jenkins). You want all the output of your code (printf's) to be redirected to a log file? I would advice just to build code that writes to a text file directly.